# SQL Server 2012 Resource Governor and memory used by CLR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

In SQL 2012 memory used by CLR is now part of what is controlled by "MAX Server Memory"

a) Does Resource Governor in SQL 2012 Enterprise (MAX_MEMORY_PERCENT for resource pool) governs CLR memory?

b) Also, Max_Memory_Percent is the percentage of "Max Server Memory"? So my max server memory is 28 GB on a server with 32 GB RAM. Does that mean setting Max_MEMORY_PERCENT to 10 percent mean I set 2.8 GB for that particular resource pool.